# How does Chrome choose which folder to put a new bookmark in?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

This baffles and enrages me; I add a new bookmark in Chrome using Ctrl+D or clicking on the Star. And the folder it places the bookmark in is some random, nested folder I haven't touched in a year.

How does Chrome decide which folder it's going to put your bookmark in? Sometimes it seems to pick the last used folder, other times it persistently uses an old folder I never add bookmarks to. Is there some way to force it to always put them in the bookmarks bar or otherwise limit it's behavior?

Comment: Did you *access* a bookmark from that folder? Do you use a bookmark management extension?

Comment: Nope, I never use the folder (basically an archive) and the only active bookmark managing tool I have is Chrome Sync (I never use the folder on other devices either)

Comment: I have always wondered that, maybe its trying to match using keywords in the url or webpage itself.

Comment: Okay, it DOES seem to be the last accessed folder when I manually manage my bookmarks, but the folder it keeps suggesting is a folder of old webcomics and cartoons I used to watch. I never use the folder or add to it, why would it keep coming up as the default (and only sometimes)?

Comment: For me, it always places new bookmark in the last folder I have choosen.

Comment: The list it gives in the folder dropdown is also baffling; most of my new bookmarks go to my UX folder, and half the time it's the default suggestion. Half the time it's *not in the list at all*

Comment: Have you filed a bug? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do.  Assuming you already have the Bookmarks bar showing and you are using a computer, using your mouse left click the icon to the left of your current URL address this is sometimes a lock on HTTPS pages and a pieces of paper with a corner folded on others and drag the URL to the bookmarks bar.  If you want to use folders simply drag your folders from the bookmarks drop down to the bookmarks bar and then you can drag the URL you are currently on into the folder on the bookmark bar using the same method.

Answer (score -1):

For me, this was due to Sort Bookmarks using the bookmarks and thus the last folder always popped up after using the plugin.